# How to launch the REST Console URL using selenium webdriver?

Tags: google-chrome, rest, selenium, webdriver

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\pugazd\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    String url2="chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn/index.html";
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url2);
}
```

I try to launch the URL with chrome browser, the browser opens with the error.

```
Error: The webpage at chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn/index.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_FAILED.
```

How do I open the REST Console ?

Thanks in Advance
Thyagu

Comment: Can you check chrome://extensions and verify (if you haven't) that your extensions ID is the same as what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Chrome does not load any extensions in the window launched by Selenium. (You can verify this by loading `driver.get("http://www.Google.com")` and checking the list of extensions.

And obviously your extension should be loaded into Chrome, for the URL (which you tried) to work.

To enable ChromeDriver to load extensions, use

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments ... I done with it.  But I got a Exception.Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://omlijhidnmlobpccmlkhjeikgbbhebab/background.html